# How to find part of a string in HL7-like freetextparameter between e.q. 2nd and 3thd | character?

Tags: sql, string, substring, ssms

In a program I created some HL7-like strings.
They look like this:

ID=1610968|EAD=02962|CNR=0|ACT=10968|ACTNAME=bijkomend honorarium voor toezicht COVID-19-patient|TIME=2/02/2023 16:21:00|EENHEID=30016|AFDCODE=KANE|AANTAL=1|URG=0|INF=0|TOPO=0|ARTS=avdbro9|SUP=avdbro9

I am looking for a SQL query in which i can split up this string in separate parts between the | character.

for instance I would like to find a way to isolate the part |ACT=10968| which always will be between the third and fourth |.

How can I do this?

thnx
c

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: Hi Nick, thnx for the feedback.
I added ssms as I am using microsoft sql management studios.
Is this sufficient as extra info?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server then try using the STRING_SPLIT function as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and then select the element you require from the output of this function

Comment: Hi, i've tried to use this as following
<SELECT * 
FROM STRING_SPLIT((select value
from FreeTextSignals
where ParameterID in (select ParameterID from Parameters where ParameterName like 'ACTA_%' and ParameterType = 4  and ParameterName not like 'ACTA__overzicht%')),'|')>

but i get error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I must confess I am a novice in sql

Comment: I think you need to look at Example B in the documentation I linked to - where it discusses using this with a table column and needing to use the CROSS APPLY approach

Comment: Hi, 

I've changed this in 
<SELECT top 1000 s.Value
FROM  FreeTextSignals s CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.Value, '|')
where s.ParameterID in (select ParameterID from Parameters where ParameterName like 'ACTA_%' and ParameterType = 4  and ParameterName not like 'ACTA__overzicht%')
>
I get a column with the same long string where I started.
If I